# Apps CTA buttons shape

Tags: mobile, buttons

Debating what should be the shape of different buttons and CTA's on my apps (both iOS & Android).
The design guidelines of Google/Apple are tending toward the simple rectangle w/o rounded corners.
Any recommendations/experience/research on usability on the topic?

Eg. these 3 options (assume that everything is equal but the corner shape)
[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1: Go with rounded corners and give importance to [affordance](https://uxdesign.cc/affordances-ad4fff2ff6c8#.5lllsd4bz).**

> Some research suggests that rounded corners enhance information
> processing and draw our eyes to the center of the element.
>
> [Buttons in UI Design: The Evolution of Style and Best Practices](https://uxplanet.org/buttons-in-ui-design-the-evolution-of-style-and-best-practices-56536dc5386e#.m482t25u9)

The post here: [How do rounded corners affect usability?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/how-do-rounded-corners-affect-usability) gives a lot better understanding on why to choose them not just in software, but for hardware as well.

---

Google's project called **web components** has already given special consideration to [button's affordance](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-button) (notice the nice shadow that makes the buttons look like buttons) along with rounded corners which are already being implemented in Android applications.

[image]